# Can I send a message to multiple hosts in one command using nc (netcat)?

Tags: linux, shell, netcat

Is it possible to do it in one netcat invocation?

This works:

```
nc WHKWDCTGABUZUN1 12345 -w 5
```

How do I make this work?

```
nc WHKWDCTGABUZUN1,WHKWDCTGABUZUN2,WHKWDCTGABUZUN3 12345 -w 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, `nc` cannot directly do what you want. But, as the man pages say, `nc` works nicely in scripts, so you can do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
ADDRESSES=("WHKWDCTGABUZUN1" "WHKWDCTGABUZUN2" "WHKWDCTGABUZUN3")
for ADDR in ${ADDRESSES[@]}
do
    nc "$ADDR" 12345 -w 5
done
```

You can wrap this into a shell script that will send whatever you pass on `stdin` to each of the hosts.

If this doesn't work for you, check out one or more of the beefed-up versions of `nc`, including [`ncat`](https://nmap.org/ncat/) and [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/), both of which are available for Linux. I'm not sure that they can do what you want either, but it's more likely.

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually do that in a single line, the way you're asking. However, something like this may work:

```
printf "WHKWDCTGABUZUN1\nWHKWDCTGABUZUN2\nWHKWDCTGABUZUN3\n" |
while read address; do 
    nc "$address" 80 -w 5 <<< GET;
done
```